# How to end a macro (or trigger a different macro) AFTER mouseover ends

Tags: excel, mouseover, vba

I overlaid a transparent active-x label box over a sheet's shape to allow a mouseover trigger to make visible an explanatory, hidden text box. Code follows.

What I want to know is if there's an ability upon leaving the mouseover state that the text box can be hidden automatically again.

Ideas?

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("IndexTBSection1")).Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: There's no "mouseout" event, so the best you could do might be to set a timer to hide the text box

Comment: ...or put a slightly larger label under the one you have, and have that label's mousemove event do the hiding (OK as long as the user doesn't move the mouse too quickly to register on the second label...)

Comment: Didn't look much into it, but what about this:
https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/tip-tricks-code/53835-mouse-over-objects-detect-when-mouse-leaves

Comment: I very much like the ozgrid solution, though it is convoluted, and the slightly larger label I tried, but you were right that if you move the mouse too quickly it could skip triggering the hiding macro.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a hyperlink to your object and use its tooltip instead, might solve your problem without much effort.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I am going to try this.

Comment: It did work, however I couldn't figure out how to format anything within the tooltip option. So I didn't end up using this.  Am I missing something about tooltips?

Comment: True, I cannot think of a way to format. I simply did not read your question as you needed to be able to format - sorry.